# ERR_REQUIRE_ESM - TypeScript + nodemon + ts-node + node-fetch

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to use `node-fetch` v3 with `nodemon` + `ts-node`, but I got all possible errors about ESM. I've tried many combination of `type` in the `package.json` file and `compilerOptions.target` in the `tsconfig.json` file, but I'm not able to simultaneously compile my script and run it in development mode.

This is my simple script:

```
import express from "express";
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import json from "json-server";

const app = express();

app.use("/db", json.router("db.json"));

app.use("/test", (req, res) => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3001/db");
  res.json({ ok: true });
});

app.listen(3001);
```

I need to be able to make it work with following two commands:

```
tsc && node index.js
nodemon -r ts-node index.ts
```

How should be `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` configured to make both the commands to work?

Please note that the problems start as soon as I add `node-fetch` to the project.

Answer (score 11):

It is currently very hard to compile typescript to native ESM I recommend downgrading node-fetch to `2.6.5`.

Node Fetch started shipping ES Modules since `3.0.0` see here:
https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/main/docs/v3-UPGRADE-GUIDE.md#breaking

If you want to go the hard route you can follow this blog: https://2ality.com/2021/06/typescript-esm-nodejs.html

The problem is that you cannot use `require('some-module')` which is built to be an ESM.
Since you're compiling to commonjs modules it will require some transpiling to make them work with ESM.

Typescript is adding `nodenext` as a module option on [typescript 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/)

Comment: Thank you, interesting reading. I'll not follow your suggestion, I prefer the hard route: one of the purposes of my question is to understand how to work with ESM modules.

Comment: I don't really understand the issue. I also don't want to spend time researching. I just want to be able to `npm i node-fetch` and be able to `import fetch from 'node-fetch'` in my typescript projects. Shouldn't be an issue today! Back to node-fetch@2 for me

Comment: the absolute state of js, expect this issue to occur for more packages soon.